# Why am I getting an error indicating that my variable doesn't exist, when I've already defined it?

Tags: c#, variables

I get an error indicating that `MyRandomArray` doesn't exist in the current context. How do you access variables across classes in a C# WinForms application?

```
public void Quiz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] MyRandomArray = getWordList();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    somefunction(MyRandomArray);/// MyRandomArray doesn't exist in the current context.
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've defined the array, but *only* in the scope of the `Quiz_Load` method, so the scope of `timer1_Tick` has no knowledge of it. If you declare it as an instance member of the class, it will be accessible from any instance method:

```
private string[] MyRandomArray;

public void Quiz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MyRandomArray = getWordList();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   somefunction(this.MyRandomArray); // No problem
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [Scope (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually it does. Your comment is invalid!

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yeah sorry, I forgot to remove it from OP's original code. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

`MyRandomArray` is [local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to the `Quiz_Load` method; therefore you can't see it in the `timer1_Tick` method. You'll have to use a field to store the array if you need it visible across instance methods:

```
private string[] MyRandomArray;

public void Quiz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.MyRandomArray = getWordList();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    somefunction(this.MyRandomArray);
}
```

Alternatively, since you have a timer ticking, when you set up the timer callback you could have, as part of the [callback state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx) you could pass along `MyRandomArray`.